# PHP - Set a array in the __construct

Tags: php, arrays, oop, file-upload

I'm creating a uploading class and I'd like to know if that is correct way.. for example

```
private $fieldname; //setting name in form
    private $type = array(); //type files: text/plain','application/msword','application/pdf
    private $folder; //folder where save my files
    private $filename; //filename :)

    public function __construct($fieldname,$type,$folder,$filename){
        $this->fieldname = $fieldname;
        $this->type[] = $type;
        $this->folder = $folder;
        $this->filename = $filename;        
    }
```

When I instance my object

```
$upload = new UploadClass('file',['pdf','photo'],'folder','filename');
```

The result is not pleasing me

```
object(UploadClass)[1]
  private 'fieldname' => string 'file' (length=4)
  private 'type' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'pdf' (length=3)
          1 => string 'photo' (length=5)
  private 'folder' => string 'folder' (length=6)
  private 'filename' => string 'filename' (length=8)
```

I think the issue of have two array is not cool.. I don't know.. Maybe you helping me this gets better.. Sorry for code! HAHA

Comment: So what is your question now? how to create a one dimensional array?

Comment: Simply `$this->type = $type;`..!?

Comment: Is not necessary type [] ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `UploadClass::type` is declared as an array and you are adding an element to it with `$this->type[] = $type;` you are seeing that result (i.e. a nested array). Basically you are adding that array to the first element of `UploadClass::type`.

Just assign that array to `UploadClass::type` and you're all set:

```
$this->type = $type;
```